# How to convert XFile to File to upload an image to remote server?

Tags: flutter

I need to upload a picture taken with the device´s camera.

Here you have the code:

```
   XFile? _image;

  Future getImagefromcamera() async {
    XFile? image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    setState(() async {
      _image = image ;
      conFoto = true;
      File file = File(image?.path);
      _upload(file);
    });
  }

 void _upload(File file) {


    if (file == null) return;
    setState(() {


    });
    String base64Image = base64Encode(file.readAsBytesSync());
    String fileName = file.path.split("/").last;

    http.post(Uri.parse(phpEndPoint), body: {
      "image": base64Image,
      "name": fileName,

    }).then((res) async {
      print(res.statusCode);
      setState(() {
        print("***********SOURCE subido:"+fileName);


      });
    }).catchError((err) {
      print(err);
    });
  }
```

I am getting an error at line

```
 File file = File(image?.path);
```

Error: `The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'`

Comment: https://kashifchandio.medium.com/upload-images-to-a-rest-api-with-flutter-using-http-61713964e1c 
did you check that thing?

Comment: @rahulVFlutterAndroid, it works as your proposed URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is, the `XFile` in your case the `image` variable can be null. So if it is null then it's not possible to get a path from it and make a file.

So just need to little `null check`. By doing this

```
File file = File(image?.path? ?? "");
```

Which says, if the path `string` doesn't exist, the use the empty `string`.
Or if you are supper confident that `image` file will definitely exist, then what you can do is, this

```
File file = File(image!.path);
```

In this case, your function will `throw` an error if the image file doesn't exist.